# Erro de passagem (laços) - jogo pedra papel tesoura lagarto e spock

Tags: python, jogos

estou fazendo um jogo Pedra, papel, tesoura, lagarto e spock.

A intenção do jogo é criar uma função que me pergunte qual opção eu vou escolher, enquanto o computador escolhe aleatoriamente um desses 5. Uma terceira função deve comparar o resultado das duas jogadas (minha e do computador) e verificar se eu ganhei, perdi ou empatou. No começo, coloquei tbm um comando para que o computador me pergunte quantas rodadas quero jogar. O problema é que aparentemente ele "trava" os valores da primeira rodada, por exemplo, se eu escolho tesoura e o computador escolhe papel, ele sempre computa o resultado dessa rodada (que ganhei) nas próximas rodadas, mesmo que eu escolha outras coisas nas proximas rodadas. Desde já obrigado.

````
legenda = '''
[0] pedra
[1] spock
[2] papel
[3] lagarto
[4] tesoura
'''
n = randint(0,4)

print(n)

lista = [[0,'pedra'],[1,'spock'],[2,'papel'],[3,'lagarto'],[4,'tesoura']]

def jogador():
    while True:
        print(legenda)
        esc = int(input(f'Escolha uma jogada: '))
        if esc == 0 or esc ==  1 or esc == 2 or esc == 3 or esc == 4:        
            print(f'-> Você escolheu {lista[esc][1]} ')
            break
        else:
            print(f'Opção inválida, digite novamente')
    return esc

def computador():
    print()
    print(f'-> O computador jogou {lista[n][1]}')
    return n

def dif():
    dife = jogador() - computador()
    return dife

def jogada():
    voce = 0
    comp = 0
    print(f'''\t\tPLACAR
VOCÊ\t\t\tCOMPUTADOR
{voce}\t\t\t\t{comp}''')
    num = int(input(f'Quant. de rodadas? '))
    for i in range(0,num):
        jogador()
        computador()
        if dif() == 2 or dif() == 1 or dif() == -3 or dif() == -4 :
            voce += 1
            print('Você ganhou')
            print(f'''\t\tPLACAR
VOCÊ\t\t\tCOMPUTADOR
{voce}\t\t\t\t{comp}''')

        elif dif() == 0:
            print('Empate')
            print(f'''\t\tPLACAR
VOCÊ\t\t\tCOMPUTADOR
{voce}\t\t\t\t{comp}''')
        else:
            print('Você perdeu')
            comp += 1
            print(f'''\t\tPLACAR
VOCÊ\t\t\tCOMPUTADOR
{voce}\t\t\t\t{comp}''')

jogada()```
````

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, fiz uma pequena alteração aqui. coloquei o randint dentro da função computador ao inves de jogar no inicio como feito anteriormente e funcionou. Parabéns pelo codigo.

```
    from random import randint
    from time import sleep
    legenda = '''
    [0] pedra
    [1] spock
    [2] papel
    [3] lagarto
    [4] tesoura
    '''
    lista = [[0,'pedra'],[1,'spock'],[2,'papel'],[3,'lagarto'],[4,'tesoura']]

    def jogador():
        while True:
            print(legenda)
            esc = int(input(f'Escolha uma jogada: '))
            if esc == 0 or esc ==  1 or esc == 2 or esc == 3 or esc == 4:
                print(f'-> Você escolheu {lista[esc][1]} ')
                break
            else:
                print(f'Opção inválida, digite novamente')
        return esc

    def computador():
        n = randint(0, 4)
        print()
        print(f'-> O computador jogou {lista[n][1]}')
        return n

    def dif():
        dife = jogador() - computador()
        return dife

    def jogada():
        voce = 0
        comp = 0
        print(f'''\t\tPLACAR
    VOCÊ\t\t\tCOMPUTADOR
    {voce}\t\t\t\t{comp}''')
        num = int(input(f'Quant. de rodadas? '))
        for i in range(0,num):
            jogador()
            computador()
            if dif() == 2 or dif() == 1 or dif() == -3 or dif() == -4 :
                voce += 1
                print('Você ganhou')
                print(f'''\t\tPLACAR
    VOCÊ\t\t\tCOMPUTADOR
    {voce}\t\t\t\t{comp}''')

            elif dif() == 0:
                print('Empate')
                print(f'''\t\tPLACAR
    VOCÊ\t\t\tCOMPUTADOR
    {voce}\t\t\t\t{comp}''')
            else:
                print('Você perdeu')
                comp += 1
                print(f'''\t\tPLACAR
    VOCÊ\t\t\tCOMPUTADOR
    {voce}\t\t\t\t{comp}''')

    jogada()
```

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver o problema de não atualizar o numero aleatório. Porém, o placar só aparece a cada 6 rodadas, não sei por qual motivo.